# Path finder in non-grid-based map

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

How would you code a path finder in a non-grid-based map?

I'm doing a 3D game with an open world. You move by clicking where you want to move, and I want to make it non-tiled-based.

Comment: A* doesn't require a grid-based map.

Comment: @candu but if it's not grid-based how do you check for collitions?

Comment: How familiar are you with graphs?

Comment: @templatetypedef Never worked with graphs for pathfinding, the thing is that the parh must be done server-side so basically the server knows nothing from the 3D world, just positions of things.

Comment: @CarlosC Can you update your question with a more complete description of the problem setup? What information is stored where? How is it stored? Where is the pathfinding to be done? With more information along those lines, we can give much better advice.

Comment: what about navigation meshes, look at this article http://www.ai-blog.net/archives/000152.html